# Cannot upgrade EC2/Ubuntu to 18.04.4 with do-release-upgrade. Maybe it's python?

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, python, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to upgrade my Amazon EC2 instance from Ubuntu 16.04.6 to 18.04.4.
I've already performed the cleanups like `apt clean`, `apt autoremove` etc...

Then I start `do-release-upgrade`, I confirm to proceed, but then this is what happens:

```
Last login: Sat Mar 21 14:41:11 2020 from 93.49.108.203
ubuntu@ip-172-30-0-90:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,242 kB]
Fetched 1,243 kB in 0s (0 B/s)
authenticate 'bionic.tar.gz' against 'bionic.tar.gz.gpg'
extracting 'bionic.tar.gz'
  Removing python3-zope.interface:amd64 rather than change python3:amd64
  MarkDelete python3-zope.interface [ amd64 ] < 4.3.2-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+1 > ( zope ) FU=0
Investigating (3) python3-twisted [ amd64 ] < none -> 17.9.0-2ubuntu0.1 > ( python )
Broken python3-twisted:amd64 Depends on python3-zope.interface [ amd64 ] < 4.3.2-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+1 > ( zope ) (>= 4.0.2)
  Considering python3-zope.interface:amd64 158 as a solution to python3-twisted:amd64 1
  MarkKeep python3-twisted [ amd64 ] < none -> 17.9.0-2ubuntu0.1 > ( python ) FU=0
  Holding Back python3-twisted:amd64 rather than change python3-zope.interface:amd64
Investigating (4) landscape-common [ amd64 ] < none -> 18.01-0ubuntu3.5 > ( admin )
Broken landscape-common:amd64 Depends on python3-twisted [ amd64 ] < none -> 17.9.0-2ubuntu0.1 > ( python )
  Considering python3-twisted:amd64 1 as a solution to landscape-common:amd64 10000
    Reinst Failed because of python3-zope.interface:amd64
  MarkKeep python3-twisted [ amd64 ] < none -> 17.9.0-2ubuntu0.1 > ( python ) FU=0
  Considering python3-twisted:amd64 1 as a solution to landscape-common:amd64 10000
Done

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-5z80tz9_/bionic", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-5z80tz9_/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 238, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-5z80tz9_/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2064, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-5z80tz9_/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1973, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.askDistUpgrade():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-5z80tz9_/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1153, in askDistUpgrade
    changes = self.calcDistUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-5z80tz9_/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1120, in calcDistUpgrade
    if not self.cache.installTasks(self.tasks):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-5z80tz9_/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeCache.py", line 856, in installTasks
    pkg.mark_install()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/package.py", line 1356, in mark_install
    fixer.resolve(True)
SystemError: E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 497, in add_to_existing
    self.write(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 450, in write
    block = f.read(1048576)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-5z80tz9_/bionic", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-5z80tz9_/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 238, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-5z80tz9_/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2064, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-5z80tz9_/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1973, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.askDistUpgrade():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-5z80tz9_/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1153, in askDistUpgrade
    changes = self.calcDistUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-5z80tz9_/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1120, in calcDistUpgrade
    if not self.cache.installTasks(self.tasks):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-5z80tz9_/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeCache.py", line 856, in installTasks
    pkg.mark_install()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/package.py", line 1356, in mark_install
    fixer.resolve(True)
SystemError: E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
=== Command detached from window (Sat Mar 21 15:00:02 2020) ===
```

What could be the reason?